# A variable is reverting to a previous value after being assigned to with an assignment statement

Tags: c++, assembly, static, chip-8

I am writing a simple chip8 emulator.

I have a value called programCounter(PC).

The problem is that once I return from the Instruction1( which modifies PC),  PC returns to the value it was before being modified by the method.

### Example

Before Instruction1 assigns to PC, the value of PC is 203.

After Instruction1, the value of PC is (0x0NNN & 0xFFFE).

By programCounter++, it return to 203 than increments.

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr auto PROGRAMSTART = 0x200;
constexpr auto GRAPHICSTART = 0xF00;
constexpr auto GRAPHICEND = 0xFFF;

//Memory
static uint8_t memory[4096]; // 0x000-0xFFF -> 0000-4095
static uint16_t stack[16];

//General Purpose Registers
static uint8_t registers[16]; //Register V0,V1,..V9,VA,VB,..,VF

//Special Purpose Register
static uint8_t specialRegisters[2];
static uint8_t stackPointer;
static uint16_t registerI;
static uint16_t programCounter = PROGRAMSTART;

//Graphic
const int WIDTH = 64;
const int HEIGHT = 32;
const int beginnningOfGraphicMemory = 0xF00;
```

For instruction 1NNN("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8#Opcode_table"),
It is a simple unconditional jump.

```
void Instruction1(uint16_t NNN)
{
    programCounter = (NNN & 0xFFFE); //Keeps the PC counter aligned to memory
}

int main()
{
    SetUpInterpreterText(0);
    Test();
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Program Counter: %04x \n", programCounter);
        uint16_t byte0 = (memory[programCounter++] << 8);
        uint16_t byte1 = (memory[programCounter]);
        uint16_t instruction = byte0 + byte1; //must load data in 16bit chunks
        Decoder(instruction);
        printf("Program Counter: %04x  Data: %04x \n", programCounter, instruction);
        programCounter++;
        
    }
    return 0;
}

void Decoder(uint16_t instruction)
{
    uint16_t data = instruction & 0x0FFF; //removing the top 4 bits to make it easier
    switch (instruction >> 12)
    {
    case 0:
        Instruction0(data);
        break;
    case 1:
        Instruction1(data);
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Instruction Not Foud" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    }
}
```

All Decoder does is remove the top 4 bits for the instructions for a 16-bit instruction. For example, 0x1234 is sent to the 1NNN instruction/Method and the 234 represents the NNN part of the instruction.

I disassembled the program and according to the assembly,
the PC is being stored in memory and once I get to the `programCounter++;' it is restored from memory. However, for the Instruction1, it doesn't write to memory it rights to the register EAX.

What should I do to let the compiler know that I want it to update the memory location of PC when ever I assign a value to it rather than just updating the register?

P.S.
I have tried writing inline assembly but I am not that skilled at x86 assembly. I can't seem to move register_EAX to the memory location of the value so I can forcibly update value since EAX has the proper value until PC is incremented.

Comment: Do you expect `Decoder` to modify the value of `instruction`?

Comment: Yes to keep the math simple.

Comment: Please show the output you get from running the program and explain how it differs from the expected otuput. And post a compilable program

Comment: Is `static uint16_t programCounter = PROGRAMSTART;` in a header file that's included by 2 or more units ?

Comment: @Codelyok13 That `static` variable is not really global.  It is a `static` variable only know to the compilation unit being compiled.  A true global variable would be declared in one compilation unit, and in all others, the `extern` keyword is used.  What you really have right now are two (or more) variables named `programCounter`, and neither one knows anything about the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two or more cpp files.  Each forms a compilation unit.  (A `.h` you include becomes part of each compilation unit separately; the notion of compilation unit applies *after* preprocessing is done.)

Static global variables are not linked between compilation units, they're private to the unit they're defined in.
`static uint16_t programCounter` is thus local to each cpp file.

As a general rule:

1. Stop using global variables, especially mutable ones.  Pass shared state explicitly.  Use a class or struct.
2. Especially stop using mutable static variables in header files.  That is insane.
3. Check the address of data when things don't make sense.

Be aware that `static` has a different meaning within classes and functions that it does at global scope.  Regular globals already have static *storage class* (same as `static` variables), but with global cross-file visibility.